# VB.NET Cannot connect to Oracle Server

Tags: vb.net, oracle

I receive the error below when running the following function.  The catch says the line where it opens the connection (Me.OracleConn.Open()).

I have made sure that the server exists in the TNSNAMES.ora file.

```
Imports NetOracle = System.Data.OracleClient
...
Private Property OracleConn As NetOracle.OracleConnection
...
    Private Function Connect_To_Oracle() As Boolean
        Connect_To_Oracle = False

        Try

            'Me.OracleConn = New NetOracle.OracleConnection
            Me.OracleConn = New System.Data.OracleClient.OracleConnection
            Me.OracleConn.ConnectionString = "Data Source = (DESCRIPTION=" & _
                      "(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = servername.net)(PORT = ####)))" & _
                      "(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME = risk)));" & _
                      "User Id=user_name;Password=password;"

            Me.OracleConn.Open()
            Connect_To_Oracle = True
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Oracle Connection Error:" & ex.Message)
        End Try


    End Function
```

[image]

Comment: This is why Oracle consultants make a good living :)  The error message googles well.  And count the parentheses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the permissions of your $ORACLE_HOME: read more at:
http://oraclepoint.com/oralife/2010/08/19/oracle-odbc-connection-issue-of-system-exception-ocienvcreate-failed-with-return-code-1-on-windows-with-asp/

Comment: I restored my computer back to a previous day when the Oracle client was working.  I did see that the ORACLE_HOME was set to the wrong client.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using ODP.Net without TNSNames? I find it quite easier than struggling with a txt file on your system...

The connection string would look something like this:

```
Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=MyHost)(PORT=MyPort)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=MyOracleSID)));User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;
```

It's basically the same information that you put on the TNSNAMES but instead you put the connection info on your web.config.